# Vis.js - set graph label's font as bold

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I use **vis.js** to display a graph. I know we can update the node with:

```
nodes.update([{
  id: 1,
  font: {
    color: "#0d8"
  }
}]);
```

However, I can't update the font weight, for example, with **font.bold: true**.

I've also tried to use **font.multi**, but no luck.

Can you show how to set existing label as bold? (potentially as normal back too)

Comment: Have you succeeded using DongBin Kim's answer? See also my comment to it

Comment: Remember that setting `font.bold` to `true` is not how it is supposed to be used: this option is to *change the font of `<b>` elements inside the label*, not to enable bold (`font.multi: "html"` does that)

Answer (score 7):

You need to combine a couple of options to make it work.

A. Set `font` option in `node` option:

```
// in the option object
nodes: {
    font: {
        // required: enables displaying <b>text</b> in the label as bold text
        multi: 'html',
        // optional: use this if you want to specify the font of bold text
        bold: '16px arial black'
    }
}
```

B. Add `html` element in the `label` option:

```
// in the option object or node data object
label: `<b>${YourLabel}</b>`
```

So basically, you only need to specify the `multi` property as `html` and add `<b>` element in the `label` property with your label text.

Comment: I've fixed the missing comma in you answer; for me it works with just `font:{ multi: "html" }` (and `<b>...</b>` in label) though

Comment: @YakovL As I mentioned, you only need to specify `multi` property and `label` property with `<b>` element. But if you want a specific bold style, you could add the `bold` property as above.

Comment: right, I've missed the comment in the code. If you don't object, I'll change the order of options to indicate the first one is required and the comments to improve readability for quick lookup

Comment: @YakovL I appreciate your feedback! That sounds reasonable :)

Comment: hi.. do you know how to embed material design icon such `<i class='mdi mdi-star'></i>`?

Answer (score 0):

var options = {axisFontSize = 30} and then pass to the graph object