# R visNetwork: how to set labels bold and increase margins around labels

Tags: r, visnetwork

I created a network graph using the `visNetwork` package (I have little knowledge of other languages, sorry).

I want two points (Please look at the left below image)

1. To make labels bold.
2. To increase space between labels and border.

Can I do them with R?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is an example code and the outputs:

```
library(dplyr); library(visNetwork)

visNetwork(nodes = data_frame(id = 1:3, 
                              label = c("abcdef", "xxx", "y"),
                              shape = "box"),
           edges = data_frame(from = c(1, 1, 2),
                              to = c(2, 3, 3),
                              arrows = "to")) %>% 
  visNodes(font = list(size = 17),
           color = list(background = "aliceblue", border = "darkblue")) %>% 
  visEdges(width = 2) %>% 
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_nicely")
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

My first ever post on StackOverflow. Found this solution by searching for non-R (i.e. Vis.js) solutions and a bit of tweaking to make it work in R.
[Vis.js - set graph label's font as bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646211/vis-js-set-graph-labels-font-as-bold)

Step 1: Wrap your labels in HTML code, `<b></b>` in this case because you want them bold. E.g. `mutate(label = paste0("<b>", label, "</b>"))`

Step 2: Enable displaying html elements in the label by including `multi = "html"` in visNodes().

Below code will make your labels bold:

```
library(dplyr); library(visNetwork)

visNetwork(nodes = data_frame(id = 1:3, 
                              label = c("<b>abcdef</b>", "<b>xxx</b>", "<b>y</b>"),
                              shape = "box"),
           edges = data_frame(from = c(1, 1, 2),
                              to = c(2, 3, 3),
                              arrows = "to")) %>% 
  visNodes(font = list(size = 17, multi = "html"),
           color = list(background = "aliceblue", border = "darkblue")) %>% 
  visEdges(width = 2) %>% 
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_nicely")
```