# Vis.js - set graph label's font as underline

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I use vis.js to display a graph. I want to use markup on the node's label.
I'm using a node of type `text`.

**What I did:**

I set `font` option in the `node` option:

```
// in the option object
nodes: {
    type: 'text'
    font: {
        multi: 'html',
    }
}
```

And I added the `<u>` tag to my label

```
// in the option object or node data object
label: `<u>${YourLabel}</u>`
```

**Result:**
My label is displayed with the `<u>` tag on the graph. As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646211/vis-js-set-graph-labels-font-as-bold), this works for `<b>` and `<i>`.

Is `<u>` not supported ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [issue 3119](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3119) in the old vis.js, only `<b>`, `<i>` and `<code>` is supported:

> With respect to HTML, the following is possible: Set option
> node.font.multi: html. This allows you to use the `<b>`, `<i>` and `<code>`
> tags within the label text for formatting.

In the current version of vis.js, it looks like that is still the case - from [`LabelSplitter.js`](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/blob/7e0e849b08e3a9f462f218e05ffab8dccf551eae/lib/network/modules/components/shared/LabelSplitter.js):

```
// Hash of prepared regexp's for tags
var tagPattern = {
  // HTML
  '<b>': /<b>/,
  '<i>': /<i>/,
  '<code>': /<code>/,
  '</b>': /<\/b>/,
  '</i>': /<\/i>/,
  '</code>': /<\/code>/,
  // Markdown
  '*': /\*/,  // bold
  '_': /\_/,   // ital
  '`': /`/,   // mono
  'afterBold': /[^\*]/,
  'afterItal': /[^_]/,
  'afterMono': /[^`]/,
};
```

Styling node content with SVG (where `<u>` can work) is shown [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/nodeStyles/HTMLInNodes.html) but there are warnings about browser support and this formats node content, not the node label.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to implement html tag at edges? for example have an icon at the edges label such as `"<i class='mdi mdi-star'></i>"` ?